# python - if availability is there, then print it out, else don't print it out

Tags: python, json, for-loop

So I am playing a bit with json and I have been stuck into a code where I print out 
`items['ids']`

which gives me a value of:

```
[
  {
    'id': '11891',
    'availability': 'IsNotThere',
  },
  {
    'id': '11892',
    'availability': 'IsThere',
  },
  {
    'id': '11893',
    'availability': 'IsThere',
  },
  {
    'id': '11894',
    'availability': 'IsNotThere',
  },
  {
    'id': '11895',
    'availability': 'IsNotThere',
  },
  {
    'id': '11896',
    'availability': 'IsNotThere',
  },
  {
    'id': '11897',
    'availability': 'IsNotThere',
  },
  {
    'id': '11898',
    'availability': 'IsNotThere',
  },
  {
    'id': '11899',
    'availability': 'IsNotThere',
  },
  {
    'id': '11900',
    'availability': 'IsNotThere',
  }
]
```

And I have been trying to figure out if it should be a for-loop including this problem. However I didn't come anywhere and here I am. Now I have been stuck and wondering how I can print out the ID where the avaliability "IsThere" otherwise just skip it?

EDIT:

```
id_list = [i for i in products['skus'] if i.get("id")]

for i in id_list:
   if i['availability'] == 'IsThere':
       print(i)
```

Comment: Show us your current code above instead of just some sample data.

Comment: @FrankAK Hello Frank! As I mentioned I have not any code for the for loop where I can print out only the availability `IsThere`. So I haven't come anywhere but stuck here. So basically if I might ask you, what kind of code are you thinking about?

Comment: Also it will be better if you tell at least in what programming language you need the solution.

Comment: @m.rp I have it written in the title! Its Python :)

Comment: @CDNthe2nd If you want to check whether exists `ids`, just do it with `get`, if return `None` means `False`, else `True`

Comment: I think it was a small missunderstanding, What I want to achieve is that I just want to print out whenever the `availability == 'IsThere'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just care about the `id`, and you can fetch by its name `id`. and you can do it like :

```
id_list = [i for i in sample if i.get("availability") == 'IsThere']
```

To print it out, just simple loop and print it.

```
for i in id_list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Yeah exactly, and from here how would I make it so it prints out only the availability items? :)

Comment: @CDNthe2nd As you said above, you print(items['ids']) and then you got those output. What if you `print(items)`? Can you paste full sample instead of part of your sample.

Comment: I just edited and as the code that is up there in the edit works now! however is there maybe a shorter way to make it all into on row of code? (I repeat again, it does work now with the code I edited)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a JSON object you can just loop it and check the fields using the fieldname as index:

```
for line in json:
    if(line['availability'] == "IsThere"):
       # if available -> print the id
       print(line['id'))
```